# php Search and replace function not workding

Tags: php, codeigniter, replace

I am working on one php project it already developed by another developer. This project developed in Codeigniter. I saw some text show in this format "{title}"

The text show like this "This is some text". I want to remove space form this text. 
So i am using PHP function search and replace. But this function not working.

This function can't replace "space" to "-" . it show me same like that "This is some text"

```
     {latest_videos}
           // in {title} = "This is some text"
        <?php   echo $tit = str_replace(' ','_','{title}'); ?>

            // I want $tit = "This-is-some-text"
            // But the str_replace give me "This is some text"

          <a href="{base_url}watch/<?php echo $tit ;?>/{id}">

        {/latest_videos}
```

Comment: Remove {} from there

Comment: I am guessing the code snippet you show is from a "view" file. If so, the previous developer is using some sort of template system. That means that the items between the braces (eg. `{title}`) are not PHP variables. You will need to accomplish the string manipulation somewhere in the controller that produces data for the view.

Comment: Have you checked docs and inbuilt function [url_title()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

^^ this contains a function that will handle the str_replace for you

Add a loop into your controller/model to build the structure as you need it

```
class controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $videos = ['latest_videos' => [
            'title' => 'Name of a video',
            'id' => 10,
        ]];

        foreach ($videos['latest_videos'] as &$video) {
            $video['url_safe_title'] = url_title($video['title']);
        }

        $this->parser->parse('view_name', $videos);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you do it like this

```
{latest_videos}
<a href="{base_url}watch/{url_safe_title}/{id}">{title}</a>
{/latest_videos}
```

This is untested so it might need tweaking but it should give you a good idea :)